# Fetch million records via REST API

Tags: mysql, laravel, rest, api

We are using an API to fetch hotel results with respect to cities. It has a limit of 400 results in an hour. In the the search query, Whenever I type four characters, it should give me a dropdown of cities starting with the character. For example, I type AAAA, it will give me a list of cities starting with AAAA. Now the problem is that the combination is 26x26x26x26 = 456976 combinations. Using the API, retrieving the combinations will take approximately 48 days. We are fetching it from Wego. And using their API.

Any idea how can I get million cities via API?

We are using Laravel, MySQL, REST API.

Thanks.

Comment: 400 results per user of your site? Or for your website as a whole? I can see where this can quickly become a problem though. I would say limit unnecessary searches by requiring the user to submit their search. You can also create your own city search that will populate this without using wego api, then once you get the exact city, you can send it to the wego api for a city ID.

Comment: You can also make a list of the most popular destination cities yourself along with their ID so it will almost act like a cache. So if it hits, you won't even have to go to the wego api. That's all I can think of only, since you can't change the limit, you can only try to limit the amount of searches done.